# Conway's theorem on the number of orbits on the set of all ordered cycles in a $d$-valent graph

Tags: graph-theory, permutations, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism, graph-isomorphism

I am trying to understand Conway's theorem on the number of orbits on the set of all ordered cycles in a $d$-valent graph. I quote it from [Cycles in graphs and groups](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/bernhard.kroen/Kantor_Cycles.pdf) by Kantor.

> Theorem $1$ (Conway) Let $G$ be a group of automorphisms of a
>   $d$-valent graph $\Gamma (d \ge 2)$. Assume that $G$ acts transitively
>   on the set of all ordered pairs of adjacent vertices. Let $X$ be the
>   set of all (ordered) cycles in $\Gamma$ each of which is also a cycle
>   occurring in some element of $G$. Then $G$ has exactly $d − 1$ orbits
>   in its action on $X$.

I would like to write down my understanding up to the current level below.

I understand that a $d$-valent graph is a $d$-regular graph. $G$ acting transitively on the set of all ordered pairs of adjacent vertices means $G$ is acting on all the edges of $\Gamma$ in a way that there is only one orbit. This should be an obvious implication of the fact that $G = Aut (\Gamma)$. Now $X$ is constructed with all ordered cycles appearing in any all elements of $G$.

So, in this scenario $G$ acts on the following sets.

1. Vertices of $\Gamma$
2. Edges of $\Gamma$
3. All cycles of $G$

This is where I am confused. If a permutation group acts on multiple sets, should not the cardinality of these sets be equal to each other? If the number of vertices in a $d$-regular (valent) graph $\Gamma$ is $n$, the number of its edges is $\frac{n d}{2}$. So, the number of elements in these three sets are not equal to each other.

So, how come $G$ is acting on all of them?